# trying to use an SPWeb object that has been closed or disposed and is no longer valid

Tags: 2010

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with this code?

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
            {

```
            SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["Tasks"];

            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
            oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

            foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
            {
                Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oListItem["Title"].ToString()) +
                    "<BR>");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you should not dispose the Rootweb, if you are using the SPContext. Microsoft has updated the best practices

here is one example mentioning

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rogerla/updated-spsite-rootweb-dispose-guidance)

Answer (score 2):

Are u disposing any SPWeb or SPSite object that you intantiated using the SPContext object? If so then you need not to dispose any of them.